# Can't find NavigationStack in autocomplete and can't run playground apps on MacOS

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swift-playground

I'm trying to work on editing grids sample app in playgrounds. It works fine on my iPad but it is not working on my Mac. I can see the code but I get an error message that minimum deployment target is 16 and there is no preview showing. MacOS is up to 13 no? So I guess it is refering to iPad OS 16? How do I fix this on my Mac?

Also the code references NavigationStack which now replaced NavigationView but in Xcode it doesn't show up in autocomplete and the compiler doesn't recognize it.

When I go into apple store both xcode and playground just say "open", there is no update option.

What do I do?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Version 13.4.1 (13F100)

Comment: Well then you need to use Xcode 14. Check out https://developer.apple.com/xcode/resources/

Comment: Ok, thnx will do. If its stable not sure why it doesn't show in the App Store or i don't see any an option from the xcode program to check for updates. For playgrounds I'm using 4.1 from May which is previewing the app there. If the sample app needs the beta version this is ridiculous.

Comment: It is stable with the latest version being 14.1, just make sure that you are on macOS 12.5+.